# Liferay startup windows 8.1 too slow

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Liferay 6.2 startup is too slow with my windows 8.1 development enviroment....

**1.- With my windows 8.1 64 bits development enviroment:**

About 12 -15 minutes startup....Changing jvm parameters, same results...too slow. The critical step is "INFO [localhost-startStop-1][AutoDeployDir:139] Auto deploy scanner started for ...." with 5-7 minutes duration. Tested with Java 6 , Java 7 and Java 8, (32 and 64 bits versions).

**2.- With the SAME windows 8 machine, but using them like virtual box host and Linux Ubuntu guest....With the same jvm parameters....**

About 3 minutes (that's a normal startup time!). With ubuntu virtual machine critical step "INFO [localhost-startStop-1][AutoDeployDir:139] Auto deploy scanner started for ...." is 30 seconds! and within a virtual machine!

**3.- With the SAME windows 8 machine, but using them like virtual box host and Windows 7 guest.....With the same jvm parameters...**

Just only 3 minutes too! And within a virtual machine!

**Definitely the problem seems to be Windows 8.1 .** ... but... what is the problem, tomcat + win8? liferay 6.2 + win 8.1?

Anyone works with Windows 8.1? I have discarted hardware problem with the Ubuntu virtual machine (only 3 minutes startup) and the Windows 7 virtual machine (only 3 minutes). I tested all posible java versions and parameters, and liferay startup is  not normal.

Comment: Maybe try to run it as administrator? To avoid any security-related issues with reading the 'deploy' folder. Right-click on "startup.bat" and "Run as administrator". I am not sure, but just an an idea. I am running my instances from withing the Eclipse and never had any slowdowns on Win8.1.

Answer (score 0):

Best combination should be

1. Windows server 2008 64bit, 64-bit JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 64-bit.
2. Windows server 2003 32bit, 32-bit JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 32-bit.